# Filter SVN log merges

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to filter all merges done to a branch   using SVN log, but i only want the merges is there anyway to filter it? Or will i just have to get all logs and grep the merges?

I tried using

```
svn mergeinfo URL/trunk URL/branches/Branch01 --show-revs merged
```

But that only gets me merges performed by a particular branch not all of them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'filter'?

Comment: I want the log to only display merges